# Php unlink file which is in use situation?

Tags: php, unlink

In my personal experience, you cannot delete something that's in use, I think unlink() will not work if the target file is in use, how do you handle that?

```
<?php unlink ("notes.txt"); // how to handle if file in use? ?>
```

Comment: can u show the code or example. so we can understand your problem in field?

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/251129/moving-a-file-while-its-in-use-how-does-it-work

Comment: done, check the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unlink` returns a boolean that you can use to detect if deletion was successful or not:

```
<?php

$file = fopen('notes.txt','w');
fwrite($file,'abc123');

$resul = unlink("notes.txt"); // ◄■■■ ATTEMPT TO DELETE OPEN FILE.
if ( $resul )
     echo "File deleted";
else echo "File NOT deleted (file in use or protected)";

fclose($file);

?>
```

You might see a warning message on screen, so turn off warnings and let your code (the `if($resul)`) handle the problem.

**Edit :**

It's possible to detect whether the file is in use or it is protected by using the function `is_writable`, next code shows how :

```
<?php

$file = fopen("notes.txt","w"); // ◄■■■ OPEN FILE.
fwrite($file,"abc123");

$resul = unlink("notes.txt"); // ◄■■■ ATTEMPT TO DELETE FILE.
if ( $resul ) // ◄■■■ IF FILE WAS DELETED...
     echo "File deleted";
elseif ( is_writable( "notes.txt" ) ) // ◄■■■ IF FILE IS WRITABLE...
     echo "File NOT deleted (file in use)";
else echo "File NOT deleted (file protected)";

fclose($file);

?>
```

To test previous code, open the properties of the file and set it to readonly and hidden, then run the code.

Comment: Is there no constant error integer for this? I want to explicitly know whether it was file protected or file in use.

Comment: @MikoChu, I edited my answer to separate the handling when the file is protected or in use.